# Place a resource controller at root of website?

Tags: laravel

How can I use a resource controller at the root of my website? I have tried:

```
Route::resource('/', CategoryController::class);
```

But no luck.

Comment: I doubt it would. Resource routes requires value to bind - but in case of `/` it have none. Check `php artisan route:list`, you'll see it. Do you really need resource controller? If you wish to create single action controller, maybe [invoke](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#single-action-controllers) is what you need?

Comment: Why should you do this? Nothing, is not a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you wouldn't do this as the first argument to that method is a resource name, not a path. Though, you can do this if you really want to by overriding the name of the route parameter that ends up getting used:

```
Route::resource('/', YourController::class)->parameters(['' => 'category']);
```

This would create the routes with a parameter named `'category'`:

```
GET        {category}        show
GET        {category}/edit   edit
PUT|PATCH  {category}        update
...
```

If you wanted to you could also update the names of these routes if needed via the `names` method.